# Pandera: Is cell based dataframe data validation possible?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, validation, pandera

Every row of my dataframe contain a record with a unique key combination. The data validation will be based on the columns and on key combination. For example, in a single column, cells may have a different min/max requirement based on the key combination.

Several questions:

1. can Pandera validate on a cell basis as opposed to column basis ?
2. does Pandera have a schema generator capable of this type of flexibility. Perhaps it scans a "golden dataframe" as a starting place to create a schema based on some provided criteria. I realize the schema generator output may need a bit of tweaking.

The library does look cool, and I am interested to pursue further.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

so you can create a validator that validates a single value at a time with the `element_size=True` kwarg, you can read more [here](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/checks.html#vectorized-vs-element-wise-checks).

```py
import pandera as pa

check = pa.Check(lambda x: 0 <= x <= 100, element_wise=True)
```

The function must take an individual value as input and output a boolean.

Can you elaborate on the exact check that you want to perform? If you want to do a dataframe-level row-wise check you can use an element-wise check at the [dataframe-level](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/checks.html#wide-checks) as a wide check.

> does Pandera have a schema generator capable of this type of flexibility. Perhaps it scans a "golden dataframe" as a starting place to create a schema based on some provided criteria. I realize the schema generator output may need a bit of tweaking.

You can use the `schema = pandera.infer_schema(golden_dataframe)` function to bootstrap a starter schema, then write it out to a file with `schema.to_script("path/to/file")` to further iterate.

Comment: Check example:  if row/column A/A = X then check row/column A/B must be less then Y.  Seems the "grouping" mechanism may be useful as well ??